# Android Google Maps v2 remove labels over custom tiles

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

I've got custom tiles that I'm displaying over the basic google map v2 API, and it works well except that googles labels for buildings are showing over my custom tiles. I don't want it to do this, but I need the rest of the tiles as I only have custom tiles for some parts of the map.

Is there anyway to disable labels under custom tiles or at all from the basic map?

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to hide the base layer completely using setMapType(MAP_TYPE_NONE) which also hides the labels. See if this helps with your use case.

Comment: This does hide the labels, except my tiles only cover a few areas of the map, and I need the Google Tiles to cover the rest. In the API v1 I was able to use an overlay to overlay the tiles OVER the map, which goes over the labels. but I'm not sure you can do that here in v2

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot place TileOverlays or GroundOverlays on top of labels. Your best option might be to use a different map type. This can be changed after the map has been created (i.e. in the `onMapReady` method by using the [`mMap.setMapType(...)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#public-final-void-setmaptype-int-type) method). Here are some possibilities:

### `MAP_TYPE_NORMAL` + Custom Map Style

You can easily create your own map styles by using the [Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/). It allows you to create a style that excludes labels entirely (among other things). Once you've created a style you like, you can copy the JSON code generated by that website and add it to the project file `res/raw/style_json.json`. It can then be applied like this:

```
mMap.setMapType( GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL );

try
{
    boolean success = mMap.setMapStyle(
            MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                    getContext(), R.raw.style_json ) );

    if( !success )
    {
        Log.e( TAG, "Style parsing failed." );
    }
}
catch( Resources.NotFoundException e )
{
    Log.e( TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e );
}
```

### `MAP_TYPE_NONE` + Custom Map Tiles

If you **need** to have labels outside of your TileOverlay, you could add a second TileOverlay of non-Google map tiles (like those provided by [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/about)). These typically include the labels within the tiles themselves. So if your TileOverlay is added with a higher [z-index](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/shapes#z-index), it will appear on top of these other map tiles!

### Map Types Without Labels

`MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE` and `MAP_TYPE_NONE` don't include labels. If you don't need **any** map data outside of your TileOverlay, using `MAP_TYPE_NONE` will save on mobile data.